# Problem with routes and menu link in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp

I have the following code into my routes file:

```
$routes->connect('/ecommerce/track', ['controller' => 'Tracking', 'action' => 'track']);
$routes->connect('/ecommerce/track/*', ['controller' => 'Tracking', 'action' => 'trackingEcommerce']);
```

when i acces to mysite.com/ecommerce/track it works, and when i access to mysite.com/ecommerce/track/1234 (with the tracking number) it works too, but when i try to access to another menú item like /contact it points to mysite.com/track/contact instead of mysite.com/contact

Comment: You'd need to show the code related to the problem, not (just) the one that is working as expected. The routes related to your `/contact` URLs, and the code (probably in your templates) that you're using to build the links would be a good start.

Comment: Thats the code to build the links: <?= $this->Html->link('Demo link',
                          ['action' => 'demo'], ['class' => 'ml-lg-4 mr-lg-4 d-lg-inline-block nav-item nav-link', 'escape' => false]
                          ) ?>

Comment: And thats the route to the demo link: $routes->connect('/demo', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'demo']);